# In PyTorch, what is the difference between forward() and an ordinary method?

Tags: pytorch

How is implementing the `forward()` method of a custom `nn.Module` class different from adding an ordinary method to that class?

I heard that the `forward()` method should only accept and return tensors, because PyTorch has implemented special processing on the input and output of the `forward()` method. But I tried inputting/outputting non-tensor objects on a `forward()` method, and implementing a module that doesn't have a `forward()` method (instead, there are multiple custom-named methods which act like `forward()` methods). Both ways worked well.

Comment: Are you aware that `.forward(..)` is called when you call an `nn.Module` as a function (via `.__call__()`)?

Comment: For example, if you wrap your model in `DataParallel` you will definitely run into problems if you don't implement `forward`.

Answer (score 7):

`forward()` method does accept any type of parameters. However, the goal of the `forward()` method is to encapsulate the forward computational steps. `forward()` is called in the `__call__` function. In the `forward()` method, PyTorch call the nested model itself to perform the forward pass.

It is encouraged to:

> NOT call the forward(x) method. You should call the whole model itself, as in model(x) to perform a forward pass and output predictions.

What happens if you do not do that?

If you call the `.forward()` method, and have [hooks](https://www.kaggle.com/sironghuang/understanding-pytorch-hooks) in your model, the hooks won’t have any effect.